# Detect invalid PHP resource stream

Tags: php, sockets

How do you detect that a stream resource is no longer valid? I have a script that apparently kills, maims, or threatens a little `fsockek_open()` connection resource so that it often goes away with no warning. Below are the var_dumps from my script.

```
resource(6) of type (stream)
resource(6) of type (stream)
resource(6) of type (stream)
resource(6) of type (Unknown) <-- causes feof() error on next check because it's not valid
```

Basic checks like `if($resource)` return TRUE which causes problems when checking like this.

```
if($resource AND !feof($resource))
```

The first boolean check on the resource works, but the feof fails causing an error because the stream is now unknown when the second half of the conditional is tested.

```
PHP Warning:  feof(): 6 is not a valid stream resource
```

Which makes examples like this not work.

```
while ($resource AND ! feof($resource)) <-- fails with error
{
    $buffer .= fread($resource);
}
fclose($resource);
```

Comment: Just a note to add to your answer ... If you're using socket streams in conjunction with `stream_select` notice that you can also determine if the connection has gone away when you perform a read on the selected socket stream because `EOF` counts as a "readable character". `$data = fread($stream, 32); if ('' === $data && feof($stream)) { /* socket connection gone */ }` ...

Comment: @rdlowrey, in this case that won't work since an attempted `fread($stream)` will result in the error above since its no longer a valid resource.

Comment: Yeah, I get that -- just adding a note for people who use the (extremely helpful) `stream_select` for operating on multiple socket streams in parallel. It wasn't worth an answer on its own. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I thought I had tried this, but a simple resource check seems to catch the problem in it's tracks.

```
if(is_resource($this->socket) AND !feof($this->socket))
{
    // goodness
}
```

Comment: I was about to post that as a possible solution. Perhaps something you might want to consider is why the resource randomly goes bad to start with. Possible memory limit, for example?

Comment: Yes, I'm working on the problem right now - but I wanted to know how to handle this for future problems. I don't like systems that can't handle errors (since they all end up with them).

Comment: Yes, I completely agree. Btw, you should mark your answer "Accepted" by clicking the check mark next to it.

Comment: @jimp, you can't accept your own (or any) answers for a couple hours.

Comment: Right. I forgot. I see (now) you have plenty of rep to already know to mark your own answer, LOL.